# How to get more documents from firestore onSnapshot?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using a limit to get documents from a collection from Firestore.

```js
        const q = query(mesRef, orderBy(FirestoreConstants.timestamp, "desc"), limit(limitMessages))
        
        const unSub = onSnapshot(q, (QuerySnapshot) => {
            let messages: Message[] = [];
            QuerySnapshot.forEach(d => {
                messages.push({ ...d.data() as Message });
            })
            console.log("We get messagses now")
            _setMessages(messages.reverse());
        })
        // ----
        return unSub
```

But once the user scrolls to the top, I want to fetch older messages (i.e. increase the limit) how do I do that?

I have implemented the same in Dart using a stream and scroll listener:

```dart
  _scrollListener() {
    if (!listScrollController.hasClients) return;
    if (listScrollController.offset >=
            listScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !listScrollController.position.outOfRange &&
        _limit <= listMessage.length) {
      setState(() {
        _limit += _limitIncrement;
      });
    }
  }

// ----

StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
     stream: chatProvider.getChatStream(_limit),
     builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
     // ----


// ----
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getChatStream(int limit) {
    return _firestoreInstance
        .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathChatMessages)
        .orderBy(FirestoreConstants.timestamp, descending: true)
        .limit(limit)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

I want to achieve same in react typescript.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `useState` hook to keep track of the message limit and then update it when the user scrolls to the top.

```
const MessageList = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[]>([]);
  const [limitMessages, setLimitMessages] = useState(10);

  useEffect(() => {
    const mesRef = collection(db, FirestoreConstants.pathChatMessages);
    const q = query(mesRef, orderBy(FirestoreConstants.timestamp, "desc"), limit(limitMessages));
    
    const unSub = onSnapshot(q, (QuerySnapshot) => {
      let messages: Message[] = [];
      QuerySnapshot.forEach(d => {
        messages.push({ ...d.data() as Message });
      })
      console.log("We get messagses now")
      setMessages(messages.reverse());
    })

    return unSub;
  }, [limitMessages]);

  const handleScroll = (e: React.UIEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    const element = e.target as HTMLDivElement;
    if (element.scrollTop === 0) {
      setLimitMessages(prevLimit => prevLimit + 10);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div onScroll={handleScroll}>
      {messages.map((message) => (
        // render each message
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```